# How to input line by line?

Tags: ruby, arrays, file-io

I intend to make a multiple_line input in ruby via a file.

I want to paste a big list of words into my file.txt like this  :

```
Banana
Apple
Orange
```

and be able to store each word separately into the array and eventually output an array pretty like this `["banana", "apple", "orange"]`.

`gets` stores the whole thing in to one position in the array and I get `["Banana apple orange"]`.

What should I do?

Comment: How do you read from the file using `gets`? And what conversion are you applying to the string read from the file that converts it into `"Banana apple orange"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IO.readlines('file.txt').map(&:strip)
# if you're wanting to downcase the strings as well do
# IO.readlines('file.txt').map {|l| l.strip.downcase }
```

Comment: That does not give the desired result.

Comment: I assumed the downcasing in the example was inadvertent, since the `gets` example didn't reflect the original text file.